# Book about a person giving in to become a zombie by going to sleep

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story a while ago, probably ~5 years now. I think it featured in a SF anthology of some kind, and it may have had a fairly simple name (like "Zombie" or "Sleep").

The basic premise is that the main character has been captured by 'zombies' who are mind-controlled/instinctive/asleep, but do not have rotting flesh. Instead, the effect is a bit like droud, in that they want to convert people to make them happy/ease their pain. The character is escorted through the facility and strapped into a machine that, through some reference to electricity, tingles and feels good. It is then turned up higher, and they start to feel sleepy. The character resists, and is told to give in by the zombies. I think they end up giving in in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [The Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Body_Snatchers)?

A novel filmed several times as *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*.

The plot is about an alien invasion. The aliens are duplicates of people. The duplicates take over when the original person falls asleep. As soon as they do so, their body crumbles to dust, and their duplicate is activated.

They aren't zombies, but they are emotionless and inhuman.

I haven't read the original book, but I've seen two of the film versions. The protagonist is captured by the aliens who  try to make him sleep. I don't know if that happens in the book.

Comment: nothing about machinery in the book.

Comment: I have heard of the body snatchers before, but I don't think the plot fits. I can't remember any surrounding details apart from the above scene, so I don't think it was a novel. Also, as releseabe points out, there is no machinery.